# A way to move multiple windows at once with the keyboard

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there an app for this? I will clarify what I'm looking for with an example.

I use [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/) to control windows on my Mac with the keyboard, and it works very well.

However, say after working with several PDF files in Preview at the same time, I reach a point where I have 4 files on the left, and 4 on the right. I then discover I need to read something in Safari at the same time as I read the PDF file, maybe instructions on how to move windows on StackExchange.

But to have these two apps, side by side, I will need to move all my Preview windows to left, so I can put Safari on the right. (Assume, not incorrectly, I have 10 Safari windows all over the screen and so moving Preview windows is easier)

So, is there a way to do this?

I just want to bind some keyboard shortcut that says, *all the windows from the current app should move to the left/right*.

Less ideal, but also alright is something that just moves all windows of all apps to left/right.